# How to echo result in list using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to print sql result in list using php.

```
<?php 
$query="select name from plant ";
$q=mysqli_query($con,$query)or die("Could Not Perform the Query");
while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
$hh=$row['name'];
}
?>
<ul id="myUL">
<li><a href="#"><?php echo $hh ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

like:-

.Mango

.Apple

.Banana

Comment: `$hh` is being over written inside your while loop. You need to output it inside of your while loop.

Comment: Put `ul` outside the while loop and add `li` inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the HTML in the `for` loop

```
<?php 
$query="select name from plant ";
$q=mysqli_query($con,$query)or die("Could Not Perform the Query");
$hh = ''; //empty string first
while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc())
{
    $hh .= '<li><a href="#">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>';
    //  ^--------------------- concat with the previous result
}
?>

<ul id="myUL">
<?php echo $hh; /* display */ ?> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 
$query="select name from plant ";
$q=mysqli_query($con,$query)or die("Could Not Perform the Query");
echo "<ul id="myUL">";
while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<li> <a href='#'>".$row['name']."</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$hh` will be the last fetched value because it's being rewritten on every loop cycle. You need to append to that instead. Take a look at this:

```
 <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

 $query = "SELECT name FROM tablename";
 $query = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die("Failed to fetch data");
 $lis = "";
 // as long as row is not empty
 while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
  $lis .= "<li> <a href='#'>".$row['name']."</a></li>";
 }
 echo "<ul>$lis</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks  for answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `$hh` is always the last row since `while($row = $q->fetch_assoc())` over writes the value of the variable with each row.

In order to output a column value in each row, you need to place the output inside of the while loop: it will do it once for each record.

You can use conditional statements for readability:

```
<!-- Start of List -->
<ul id="myUL">

<?php

    $query = "select name from plant ";
    $q     = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("Could Not Perform the Query");

    while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()):

?>

    <!-- Option -->
    <li><a href="#"><?= $row['name']; ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
<!-- End of List -->
```

Like referenced by @Cid in the comments, each element needs to be added inside of the list. Keep your `<ul>` outside of the loop.

In pseudo code, so you can understand better, it would look like this:

```
list
    foreach row do:
        output option
    end foreach
end list
```